# Importing data to MySQL from MS SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database-design

I want to import data from MS SQL Server, run it through some sort of regexp to filter out stuff, and import it into MySQL. I then, for each query, wish to display a relevant image from a third database. What would be the easiest way to do this, importing and linking wise?

Thank you.

Clarification: It is a php application to filter data from another database, and then for each record show an associated image from a 3rd database. It is from scratch...

Comment: Hi, re-tagged this to merge mssql tags into sqlserver.

Comment: hrm why would you have to even import the data into mysql then? just query whatever database and display the image...

Answer (score 2):

You can try the MySQL Migration Toolkit.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Now archived at http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-migration-toolkit

Comment: Note that the migration toolkit reports that it requires JRE 1.4.2 or 5.0. The toolkit is end-of-life, but a migration plugin is on the cards for MySQL Workbench as noted at http://dev.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html (in the section headed EOL of MySQL Query Browser, MySQL Administrator, MySQL Migration Toolkit).

Answer (score 1):

use SQL Management Studio (or Enterprise Manager depending on version) with the SQL Server import wizerd to get it into MS SQL.

From there you can export it to Mysql using the MySQL connector drivers.

As for as displaying an image from a third database, that is completely up to the code you have written in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Microsoft SQL Server Data Publishing Wizard (free). You can use it to script your entire database (including insert statements.) You'll have to edit this script a little bit probably to get it to run in MySQL. Now you just have a regex problem. You can try:

- Manipulating the data in MS SQL via a query, or from code (using regex) the transfer.
- Running your regexes on the script file itself, maybe try some macros, find and replace, etc.
- Manipulating the data in MySQL via a query, or from code (using regex) after the transfer.