# Import data from Microsoft SQL (.MDF) file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, import

I am running `PHP/5.3.0` with `Apache/2.2.17 (Win32)` in my Windows Vista PC. I have MySQL server version: 5.5.8. I have a Database.MDF file containing some tables. I want to import this data into my MySQL database. I have Microsoft SQL Server installed. I use PHP MyAdmin. Anybody got a solution or a software package?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the related questions? --> --> -->

Comment: @webturner can u give me a link?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have MSSQL installed the simplest option would be to install [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx), attach your mdf, then export from there.  You have quite a few options, from the simplest csv export/import, using a tool such as [OpenDbCopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/), or writing custom code to connect to both database and load from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out?
[Importing data to MySQL from MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182784/importing-data-to-mysql-from-ms-sql)

Or you can manually create the nysql tables, export the data from the MS into svg file and try importing it to mysql.