# Copy MSSQL data to MySQL DB every 5 mins?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, transfer

I'm looking for some advice over the best way to transfer data from a local MSSQL DB to a remote MYSQL database every 5 mins?
At the moment I am using a tool called SQLYOG which allows me to create a connection to my local MSSQL database and to my remote MYSQL server and set up some queries and mapping.
It also allows me to create a windows scheduled task which runs every 5 minutes.
This solution has been working ok but is only about 95% reliable and seems to struggle sometimes.
This software runs in GUI mode and via cmd prompt so is reasonably light weight when running a scheduled task.

Does anyone know of any other light weight tools or methods I can use to get the same outcome?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "seems to struggle", any indication of what goes wrong? You may have the same problems with any other tool, so it might be worth investigating what goes wrong with the existing setup.

Comment: Have a look at [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL. You can use ODBC format as source for SQLServer; save template file with options and use it in command-lime mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377252/import-data-from-microsoft-sql-mdf-file-into-mysql/11935086#11935086

Answer (score 2):

You can use SymmetricDS. its a good & efficient open source tool for this purpose.

Comment: Ahh i had forgotten about SymmetricDS, i will look into this again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx) packages to do that.

[SQL Server Integration Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) (SSIS) is a component of the Microsoft SQL Server database software that can be used to perform a broad range of data migration tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:
1. create linked server to mysql then copy rows via linked server in sp, set sql job to execute.
2. build ssis package and run it in sql job.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is the best soultion for this is to design an ETL job using either [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) or [Talen Open Studio.](http://www.talend.com/download)